# Limit proxy_pass to a variable location containing a wildcard name

Tags: regex, nginx, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I have a configuration where I use two servers, one as a proxy and one containing all business logic, databases and so on.

On the proxy serve I use nginx for establishing SSL connections to the outside world, so that business logic is only available in the intranet.

Using the proxy i want to restrict access to some parts of the business logic. I only want to provide access to the API of a GeoServer but not to the management interface. Therefore I restrict access to a location like `/geoserver/abc_def/wfs`. I use the following proxy configuration:

```
location ~ "^/geoserver/(?<building>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/wfs(?<req>.*)" {
    proxy_pass http://x.y.z.a/geoserver/$building/wfs$req;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

This works except for the query string. A valid request would be `/geoserver/abc_def/wfs?version=2.0.0&service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities` but the query string starting with `?` is not passed by the proxy.

Also this seems kind of wrong to me. **Actually I only want to restrict the location `/geoserver/*/wfs` in order to be proxied.**

Comment: what about this location: `location ~ "^/geoserver/.+/wfs$"`

Comment: @danielgpm then I get this message: `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block`. `proxy_pass` is still `proxy_pass http://x.y.z.a/geoserver/;`

Comment: and in addition the URL doesn't end after /wfs. this is just the pattern describing the reachable destinations. At least there are query params.

Comment: the *url* ends with wfs as far as the location is concern since the query args are not analyzed by the regex. You can use $arg_name or $args to check any request args. More here: [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)

Answer (score 0):

query args are not being captured in location directive, they can be accessed by $args variable

also $is_args variable contains question mark, if $args is not empty

so seems you need something like this

```
location ~ ^/geoserver/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/wfs$ {
proxy_pass http://x.y.z.a/geoserver/$1/wfs$is_args$args
...
```